# Quaternions: ellipse effect

Tags: nt.number-theory, quaternions

I would be interested in an explanation of the "six ellipse effect" produced by the pseudocode below (I also wonder how close are these to being actual ellipses). Note the code is somewhat similar to the OEIS definition of [A108618](https://oeis.org/A108618).

**Update** The original code, below, had + and - switched, i.e. was not representative of the data (also fixed parenthesis).

```
X = .5(i + j + k + e) 
Y = e (e is unit)
n = 1
result = empty list to hold results

# Define X(i) as the coefficient of i in X, X(j) as the coefficient of j in X, etc. 

0  Z = X*Y # quaternion multiplication (i*j = k, j*i = -k, i*e = i, etc)
10 
20 if n mod 3 == 0: 
30   Z(j) = Z(j) - (floor(Z(i)) - Z(i))/2
40
50 else if n mod 3 == 1: 
60   Z(k) = Z(k) - (floor(Z(j)) - Z(j))/2   
70
80 else if n mod 3 == 2: 
90   Z(i) = Z(i) - (floor(Z(k)) - Z(k))/2  
100 
110 n = n + 1
120 
130 Y = Z
140 
150 result.add(Y(e))
160
170 goto 0
```

Plotting result(n) vs result(n+1) gives the following (zoomable) plot:
[Plotly: Six Ellipses](https://plot.ly/~BlackBeard/164/floretions-six-ellipses/) (the data for the plot is [here](https://plot.ly/~BlackBeard/159/)). A youtube slow-mo of this [starts at 1:12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKL4Lkw-rU0). Note there are many small variations of this code which produce very different results- for example, where it appears ellipses are "filling up" or graphs like [this](https://plot.ly/~BlackBeard/225/x-vs-z/) which appear to be more or less symmetric about the x-axis. 
[image]

```
Z: + 0.5e + 0.5i + 0.5j+ 0.25k (n = 1) - 0.375e + 0.1875i + 0.625j + 0.375k (n = 2) - 0.78125e - 0.21875i - 0.359375j + 0.21875k (n = 3) - 0.2109375e - 0.2109375i - 0.7890625j - 0.45703125k (n = 4)
```

**Update** Removing the terms with the floor function produces apparent ["touching" ellipses](https://plot.ly/~BlackBeard/264/floretions-touching-ellipses/). Data is [here](https://plot.ly/~BlackBeard/265/). The ellipses can also be made to overlap. Side note: in my actual program X and Y look like this

```
X = .5(ieEE + jeEE + keEE + eeEE) 
Y = eeEE (eeEE is unit)
```

since I'm working with 4th order floretions- a quaternion can be seen as a 1st order floretion.

Comment: Can the floor function be replaced? Is it constant on each apparent ellipse?

Comment: There seem to be overlapping cases too ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GKD1t1MeBM) was linked from the youtube video provided)

Comment: What I meant was to ask whether the floor function could be replaced by a simpler function, say something depending on $n \mod 3$ but constant in the argument, that does not change the trajectories.

Comment: I can't reproduce your data. What are the first few values of $Z$?

Comment: O.k. sorry, neither could I as "+" and "-" were switched (fixed).
Here are the first few values of **Z**:

 + 0.5e + 0.5i + 0.5j+ 0.25k (**n = 1**)
 
 - 0.375e + 0.1875i + 0.625j + 0.375k (**n = 2**)
 
 - 0.78125e - 0.21875i - 0.359375j + 0.21875k (**n = 3**)
 
 - 0.2109375e - 0.2109375i - 0.7890625j - 0.45703125k (**n = 4**)